# Problem with db.Database.SqlQuery() usage in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am a newbie in C#. I wrote a code as below

```
TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();
string data = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select PASSWORD from User where USERNAME='admin'").FirstOrDefault();
```

When I execute this code, an error appears:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Why did this happen? I already have a table named "User".

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Because User is probably a reserved word, you’ll have to escape it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thx. It works after changing the table name from User to something else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 10):

Change you sql query to below code:

```
"select [PASSWORD] from [User] where [USERNAME]='admin'"
```

and let us know, which database are you using? (SQL Server or MySQL or ...)

**"And avoid naming your DB tables, columns, etc. using reserved keywords"**

Comment: And avoid naming your DB tables, columns, etc. using reserved keywords +1.

Answer (score 0):

`User` is a typical SQL reserved word.

Not a good practice to use SQL reserved words for a table name.

A list of reserved words here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words